Graphic problems on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I've recently installed Ubuntu on my machine. I have several graphical problems on my system:

Phantom display:
I've already solved this by turning it off via xrandr, but I found it weird as I only have one HDMI display connected. This display caused my mouse to go off-screen or to open invisible windows.
High frame time:
I am a game developer, and I use Godot 4 game engine. I experienced several bugs that I didn't have on Windows before. One of these is pretty annoying and is the high frame time, in fact some frames reach 50ms during mouse click input. I profiled my code and the problem is not there. I noticed it must be an issue with the driver or the compositor when I used fullscreen instead of windowed. The problem doesn't happen in fullscreen mode. I wanted to use another compositor and this brings us to the next problem:
Unstable Ubuntu on Wayland:
I tried to switch to Wayland, but the windows are for some reason undecorated and severely unstable graphically, glitching, and the archive app doesn't open and crashes. I can't find a solution to this problem.

My machine:
My hardware may not be the newest, but it worked fine on Windows:

HW model: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. MS-7B19
CPU: Intel® Core™ i3-8100 × 4
Memory: 16GB

My system is installed on a 250GB SSD and I have an external 1TB HDD.
What I tried:
I disabled the phantom display and it doesn't annoy me anymore. Wayland doesn't work. Is there another compositor I can try, or maybe how do I make Wayland work correctly? I tried reinstalling the graphic drivers, and even different versions, but nvidia sucks on Linux I guess, so it didn't change (reinstalling them by command messed it up even more, that it didn't even detect HDMI).
Thank you in advance.
Edit:
Maybe the inxi info about graphics could be useful to you:
Graphics:

Device-1: NVIDIA GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] driver: nvidia v: 535.171.04
  Device-2: Aveo UVC camera (Bresser microscope) driver: uvcvideo type: USB
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
    loaded: nvidia gpu: nvidia,nvidia-nvswitch resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: kms_swrast,nvidia,swrast
    platforms: gbm,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: nvidia mesa v: 535.171.04
    renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
  API: Vulkan v: 1.3.275 drivers: N/A surfaces: xcb,xlib


I am Luís. I faced similar problems running Ubuntu 24.04 under nvidia but it all was solved when I purged the previous default driver(535 as well) and installed the newest(555) via this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
You can follow this simple guide, which explains step-by-step the process: https://github.com/oddmario/NVIDIA-Ubuntu-Driver-Guide?tab=readme-ov-file
It also has a common troubleshooting reference you may find useful, as it refers explicitly to the phantom/ghost display, the fact that since the 555.42.02 driver was introduced, explicit sync was added...
If it is not enough, and you still have issues, consider checking the links at the final of the guide; they refer to reported(some solved) specific but related problems at askubuntu, nvidia and other forums.
Good luck!

Thank you very much! I installed the latest 555 drivers and updated all the grub options to fix Wayland issues. The Wayland session is still unstable and some windows are not visible. The options are correctly set testing them on the terminal.

Also, the frame lag issue I have by running my game is still there. The issue is likely with the compositor. The problems with Wayland seems to be caused from the fact there is no explicit sync on Gnome 46.0, which is the default on Ubuntu LTS and they seem reluctant to ship it soon in 46.1, since it has such an important change.
I will mark this answer as solved, since it gives many useful references and the problem seems to be currently not solvable on Ubuntu.
